# "На академии" или только "в академии"?

Tags: предлоги

Есть ли хоть одна ситуация, когда можно употреблять "на академии"?

Например, если описываются события, которые прошли на территории спортивной академии ("На академии завершился футбольный турнир", "На [полях] академии прошли отборочные матчи"), или использование этого предлога будет безграмотно в любом случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: **В академии завершился футбольный турнир, в академии прошли отборочные матчи.** Это **книжная речь**, что видно по лексике, по структуре предложений (завершился, прошли отборочные матчи).

В этих случаях предлог В не применяется, сравнить: В казанской Академии тенниса завершился VII Международный юношеский теннисный турнир ITF «Кубок Ельцина-2017».

Предлог НА может использоваться **в разговорном стиле,** когда падежная форма приобретает **дополнительные или обобщенные значения**: в академической среде, на территории академии. **Смешение стилей не допускается, вот это уже будет безграмотно.**

**Примеры**

1) Из Нацкорпуса: Вчера **на академии** (= на территории академии, среди сотрудников академии) спрашивал Алексея Григорьевича Ивахненко, моего приятеля, математика, спеца по моделям. [Н. М. Амосов. Дневник (1985)]

2) Возможный **вариант разговорной речи**: У нас на академии вчера играли последние отборочные матчи.

**Сравнить:** существует фразеологизм "первый парень на деревне" с предлогом НА, который тоже имеет обобщенное значение: среди местных, деревенских. Песня также есть: "От людей на деревне не спрятаться...".

**АКАДЕМИЯ,**  1. Название научных учреждений, задачей которых является развитие наук или искусств. А. наук России. А. художеств.  2. Название некоторых высших учебных заведений.  Военно-воздушная а. Военно-медицинская а. Поступить, принять в академию. Исключить из академии.

Comment: В своем дневнике Амосов пишет: "Неделя была трудная - 6 операций, **три заседания в академии**.....  Вчера на академии  спрашивал Алексея Григорьевича Ивахненко" (http://icfcst.kiev.ua/amosov/bookru/241). Это укрепляет меня в мысли, что Амосов имел в виду "на заседании академии".

Comment: Неважно, что конкретно обозначает падежная форма "на академии" в дневнике Амосова (это всё частности), главное - это упрощенно-обобщенная форма, которую ГРАМОТНЫЕ люди могут позволить себе в приватном разговоре (в том числе в дневниковой записи), но только не в официальной книжной речи. Ведь вопрос был именно об этом: в какой ситуации можно сказать "на академии" или это говорить категорически запрещается.

Comment: На мой взгляд, "на академии" позволительно ТОЛЬКО в смысле "на заседании академии" и т.п., где опущено слово после "на",
скажем, "на чемпионате академии"

Comment: Здесь скорее можно говорить о метонимии (переносе значения с целого предмета на его  часть),  когда  заседание академии, территорию академии, чемпионат  академии называют просто "академией",  но это в любом случае разговорная упрощенная речь, понятная узкому кругу "своих" людей.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поставлен недостаточно точно. "На академии" может употребляться в единственном и множественном числе. Примеры:

*На академии наши нашел черный год: едва в Российской почил Соколов, как в академии наук явился вице-президентом фокусник, а [Дондуков-Корсаков] его паяс*. [А. С. Пушкин. Письмо И. И. Дмитриеву (1835.04.26)]

*На Академии экономить не будем.*  [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 2 (1960)]

*Сегодня общественное мнение при обсуждении проблем науки сфокусировано на Академии наук*. [Дан Медовников, Александр Механик. Свобода науки как государственная необходимость // «Эксперт», 2013

Если сузить вопрос и рассматривать только случаи с вопросом "где?", то мой ответ таков.

Нигде не встречал "на академии" за одним исключением, которое нашел в Нацкорпусе:

*Вчера на академии спрашивал Алексея Григорьевича Ивахненко, моего приятеля, математика, спеца по моделям. [Н. М. Амосов. Дневник (1985)]*

Очевидно, имелось в виду "на заседании академии", такое бывает со словом "заседание", например, пишут "на совете" вместо "на заседании совета", "на директорате" вместо "на заседании директората":

*Курьёзу с голосованием на совете если и рассмеялись, то из вежливости*. [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

… *Недавно мне сообщили, что Валерия Цурикова пригласили в Париж для доклада и демонстрации «ИМ» на директорате ЮНЕСКО.* [Леонид Лернер. Прошедший сквозь стену // «Огонек». № 3, 1991]

А примеры, приведенные в вопросе, нельзя считать грамотными.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли хоть одна ситуация, когда можно употреблять "на академии"?

Нет, в подобном значении (где?) подобное будет нарушением орфоэпической нормы. Ваши примеры неверны, там требуется предлог В.

Разумеется, можно придумать много примеров, отвечающих на другие вопросы (на чем?, на что?) с омонимичными формами слова "академия".

Они есть в других примерах, могу предложить еще варианты (На "Академии" в автобус набился народ = в значении на остановке "Академия"), но не думаю, что они вас интересуют.